# Using jQuery to populate ValidatorHookupControl

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following form items:

```
Medications:    
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="meds" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes (list below)</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

Medication List:
<asp:CustomValidator ID="val_medsList" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="check_medsList" 
   OnServerValidate="val_medsList_ServerValidate" ValidationGroup="GroupSave" ValidateEmptyText="true"
   ErrorMessage="required" ControlToValidate="medsList" EnableClientScript="true">
</asp:CustomValidator><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="medsList" CssClass="jQueryMedsListTarget" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" 
    Width="500" MaxLength="500" Wrap="true" Rows="3" />
```

The idea is if "Yes" is selected the textbox needs to be filled out and the opposite is true if "No" is selected. In order to have the "Yes"/"No" options trigger the custom validator I use 'ValidatorHookupControl' as such:

```
ValidatorHookupControl(document.getElementById('meds_0'), document.getElementById('val_medsList'));
ValidatorHookupControl(document.getElementById('meds_1'), document.getElementById('val_medsList'));
```

This works for me, but this will become annoying when I have more than two options. I created the following to loop through all of the options but it doesn't seem to work ("yes" and "no" do not trigger the custom validator):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    hookupRadioButtonListToVal($('input[id^=meds_]'), $('#val_medsList'));
}); 
function hookupRadioButtonListToVal(rbl, validator) {
    $(rbl).each(function () {
        ValidatorHookupControl($(this), $(validator));
    });
}
```

I assume I am not returning the correct type of element with `$(this)` and `$(validator)` but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: `ValidatorHookupControl` takes DOM elements, not jQuery elements. Change `($(this), $(validator))` to `(this, validator)`. There may be other issues; this is the first I saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the final solution ended up being

```
function hookupRadioButtonListToVal(rbl, validator) {
    $(rbl).each(function () {
        ValidatorHookupControl(this, $(validator)[0]);
    });
}
```

This uses the idea that jbabey shared with a tweak to the validator portion. Unfortunately if I just called `ValidatorHookupControl(this, validator);` I would get `TypeError: val.style is undefined`